# is it possible to deploy a file to artifactory directly as a filtered resource?

Tags: artifactory

We deploy tool settings files as filtered resources so we can publish a static link for developers to download them with credentials and (we template more than just the credentials but that's the key element). I don't see anything in the REST API to indicate to set the *Filtered* setting for the file, either as part of the [deploy](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifact) or as a separate API call to enable the setting for an already published file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artifactory is using the `artifactory.filtered` property to indicate whether an artifact should be a filtered resource.
You can use the [set item properties](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-SetItemProperties) REST API method for setting this property, for example:

```
curl -uuser:password -XPUT http://artifactory.mycompany/api/storage/repo-key/path/to/my/file?properties=artifactory.filtered=true
```

This means you first have to deploy the file and than perform the above request in order to set the property value.
You can also do it in one request using [matrix parameters](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+Properties+in+Deployment+and+Resolution), the URL format for deployment should be in the following format:

```
http://artifactory.mycompany/repo-key/path/to/my/file;artifactory.filtered=true
```

Comment: Will that command both publish the file _and_ set the filtered property, or do I need to deploy first and then have a second call to mark it filtered?

Comment: If that call doesn't do both at once, can I use matrix parameters to deploy with property?

Comment: yes, you should use matrix params if you want to do it in one request. I updated the answer to reflect this